# Nested IF Statement in Excel Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, formula

I am writing an excel function that basically says this:

If B2 is blank, do nothing.

If B2 has text in it, then check to see if I2 is blank.

If I2 is blank, then check to see if H2 is less than Zero.

If H2 is less than Zero, return "No", otherwise return "Yes"

If I2 is NOT blank, then check to see if I2 is less than Zero.

If I2 is less than Zero, return "No", otherwise return "Yes"

I have written the function as below, however, I am getting an error. I have looked it over numerous times and I am not sure what is wrong. A pair of fresh eyes and help is much appreciated.

```
IF(B2="", "", (IF(I2="", (IF H2<0, "No", "Yes"), IF(I2<0, "No", "Yes"))))
```

Comment: `(IF H2` should be `IF(H2`. and `(if(...))` doesn't need the external `()` either.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `(` in the wrong places:

```
=IF(B2="", "", IF(I2="", IF( H2<0, "No", "Yes"), IF(I2<0, "No", "Yes")))
```

Comment: Oh my goodness- I don't know how I missed that. Much appreciated!